# How to configure a mac (Sonoma) to output to the speakers both audio from Spotify and from aux karaoke mic?

Tags: microphone, macosx

I'm planning for a karaoke party and we thought that we would use wireless mics to sing along to Spotify. But I'm worried about audio feedback loops, or MacOS software not allowing for split audio routing.
What would be the best way to set this up?

Comment: I double checked if this question if off limits for this SE site but its the closest I could find.

Comment: Yes this question is off topic here and will probably be closed but you can look up how to setup an aggregate device on Mac.

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of the term `aggregate device` I will try to figure this out